# How are pthreads condition variables implemented in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pthreads

What I mean is some kind of pseudocode showing how condition variables operations (signal, wait) are implemented using kernel primitives (mutexes, wait queues etc).

Comment: Why don't you just look into the _real_ code in libc?

Comment: You might like to dig around here: http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/libc/nptl/

Comment: There's more than *one* pthreads library for Linux, which can be pertinent if you are not x86 and/or GNU libC centric.

Answer (score 0):

There is some vagueness in the question: wait-queues are internal Linux kernel mechanism and they are not exported to user space. User space condition variables are implemented by libc on top of futexes.

There is no condition variable interface implementation in the Linux kernel, but it is easy to create one, see http://www.geocities.ws/nikitadanilov/code/kcond.c for example.